# How to stop locking record with Transactional anotation?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, web

My web application have this problem of occasionally getting DB deadlock. The problem turn out to be getting 2 requests in the almost the same times. 1 request is try to query the status of record while another request is trying to update the same record. So, it seems even the query request also try to lock the record while reading it. So, I wonder whether I can use

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
```

to force it to be read without locking ?

In case that we have DAO libraries that do that actually reading, do I need the propagation to something like Never. To me, this is purely read only so I don't see why I need transaction for that.

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true, propagation = Propagation.NEVER) or 
@Transactional(readOnly = true, propagation = Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED)
```

Any idea how to do that with Spring and Hibernate is very much appreciated. 
I am using Spring 1.5, Hibernate 3.6 and DB is MS SQL.

Comment: Reading and even writing to DB through Hibernate, does not create locks in DB unless you explicitly specify or config it differently. Also, `readonly` is a dialect level attribute and there is nothing like a readonly transaction in database level. And for propagation please read documentation here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html

Comment: If your requests are on different connections check the [isolation level](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems)) you're using. Databases with isolation levels above read committed will lock on SELECT's.